# React component create a new instance of the state when re-rendering even the state is not changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm using `Socket.IO` with `React.js` and I want the websocket to start only when a specific component is rendered, so I use the websocket as a state of that component, like this:

```js
const Comp = () => {
  const [ws] = useState(socketIO());
  // ... the rest of the component ...
};
```

But when the `Comp` re-rendering, it creates new websocket connection, even I don't make any changes on the connection. After a while, I end up with more than 10 websocket connections. How can I make the component keep 1 connection only? I don't want the websocket connection to become global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that functional components are just functions, all the usual things you know about functions apply. Although hooks do some seeming-magic behind the scenes (it's not really magic, it's just they have context information we don't see), the code in your component function runs according to the usual rules. That means this code

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [ws] = useState(socketIO());
  // ... the rest of the component ...
};
```

will **always** call `socketIO` so it can pass the return value of it into `useState`.

To calculate a value only **once**, when the component is first created, use a ref ([`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)) to represent non-state instance information (the kind of thing you would have stored directly on a class component instance), like this:

```
const Comp = () => {
  const {current: instance} = useRef({});
  const ws = instance.ws = instance.ws || socketIO();
  // ... the rest of the component ...
};
```

The `{}` is still evaluated every time `Comp` is called, but that overhead is trivial. What you get back from `useRef` is an object with a `current` property referring to a mutable object — one which will always be the same throughout the lifetime of the component. The second line uses the `ws` property of that object, initializing it the first time if it's falsy.

This usage is called out in the [`useRef` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

> However, `useRef()` is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.

Here's an example with a stand-in for `socketIO`:

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;

function socketIO() {
  console.log("socketIO called");
  return {};
}

const Comp = () => {
  console.log("Comp called");
  const {current: instance} = useRef({});
  const ws = instance.ws = instance.ws || socketIO();
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {counter} <input type="button" value="+" onClick={() => setCounter(c => c + 1)} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Comp/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

I should note that it's tempting to use `useMemo` here, but `useMemo` doesn't guarantee that your function to build the memoized result won't be called a second time. `useMemo` is for performance optimization, not semantics. From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo):

> **You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.** In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without `useMemo` — and then add it to optimize performance.

*(their emphasis)*

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But would you explain to me the chaining assignment here please: `const ws = instance.ws = instance.ws || socketIO();`?

Comment: @TríPhan - That expression works like this: It evaluates `instance.ws || socketIO()`, which means the `||` operator evaluates the left-hand operand (`instance.ws`) and if the result is *truthy* (anything other than `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, or `false`), it takes that value as its result. If the left-hand operator's value is *falsy* (any of those values), it evaluates the right-hand side (the call to `socketIO`) and takes that result as its result. Then the first assignment (`instance.ws = x`, where `x` is the result of the first expression) is done. The result of...

Comment: ...an assignment is the value that was assigned, so the result of that expression is `x` too. Then the `ws = x` part is done. So the first time your component is created and `Comp` is run, since `instance` will be a blank object, `instance.ws` will be `undefined` and `socketIO` will get called; the result will be assigned to `instance.ws` and `ws`. The next time `Comp` is called, `instance.ws` will already have a truthy value, so `socketIO` isn't called and `ws` gets that value.